# Flask-Admin: add filters on foreign keys

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I am using `Flask-Admin` to create a back-end interface for my application. I want to add some filters in an Admin View, but I get this error:

```
'Exception: Unsupported filter type column_name'
```

Where column name is a column field that is a Foreign Key.

Here are the models:

```
class Keywords(Base):
    id = Column(String(4), primary_key=True)
    language = Column(ForeignKey('w_accounts.language'))
    camp_type = Column(ForeignKey('w_camp_types.camp_type'))
class KeywordsAdmin(BaseAdmin):
   column_searchable_list = ('toa_id', 'name', 'toa')
   column_list = ('toa_id', 'language', 'camp_type', 'name', 'aliases', 'toa', 'toa_type')
   column_filters = ('language',)
```

After going through the API, I tried to add the following attribute as well:

```
       column_select_related_list = ('language',)
```

Instead of getting an error immediately, I get an exception when I load the page on the browser,

```
"AttributeError: 'ColumnProperty' object has no attribute 'mapper'"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add relationship.

```
class Keywords(Base):
    id = Column(String(4), primary_key=True)
    language = Column(ForeignKey('w_accounts.language'))
    camp_type = Column(ForeignKey('w_camp_types.camp_type'))

    language_ref = relationship("w_accounts", backref=db.backref('keywords', lazy='dynamic'))
```

And then:

```
column_select_related_list = ('language_ref',)
```

Comment: I am using `flask-admin` 1.6.0 and `column_select_related_list` has been deprecated.